# tikz-uml node position not as expected

Tags: tikz-uml

See below example, I expect:

1. The distance between nodes is measured by border but not center.
   A,B,C is overlapped now.
2. node E should be below D, now it's overlapped on D.
3. The middle point of D and A is measured by center, I expect it's meansured by border.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\tiny\begin{tikzpicture}[show background grid]
    \def\dx{0.5cm}
    \def\dy{1.5cm}
    \umlclass{AAAAAA}{}{};
     \umlclass[left=\dx of AAAAAA]{BBBBBBBBB}{}{};
     \umlclass[right=\dx of AAAAAA]{C}{}{};
    \umlclass[below=\dy of AAAAAA]{D}{}
    {+foo()\\
    +bar()\\
    +hello()};
    \umlclass[below=\dy of D]{E}{}{};

    \node[circle,fill=black] (M) at ($(D)!0.5!(AAAAAA)$) {};
     \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{D}{AAAAAA};
     \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{M}{BBBBBBBBB};
     \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{M}{C};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this can be simply and without your problems draw by pure `tikz` :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what happens, but for some reason it doesn't work when you use macros for the lengths. Replace `\dx` by 0.5cm, and it works fine. An alternative approach that does work (here at least) is to use `declare function` for `dx`  and `dy`. For the last point, you can specify the `north` and `south` anchors to get the midpoint between the  borders.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  show background grid,
  declare function={
    dx=0.5cm;
    dy=1.5cm;
  }
]

    \umlclass{AAAAAA}{}{};
    \umlclass[left=dx of AAAAAA]{BBBBBBBBB}{}{};
    \umlclass[right=dx of AAAAAA]{C}{}{};
    \umlclass[below=dy of AAAAAA]{D}{}
      {+foo()\\
       +bar()
       +hello()};
    \umlclass[below=dy of D]{E}{}{};

    \node[circle,fill=black] (M) at ($(D.north)!0.5!(AAAAAA.south)$) {};
    \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{D}{AAAAAA};
    \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{M}{BBBBBBBBB};
    \umlinherit[geometry=-|]{M}{C};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```